# Taking input from a file and writing to it in the same command

Tags: command-line, redirect

My `encoder` is a program that encodes a piece of text and prints the encoded text to the standard output. But when I do:

```
cat file.txt | encoder > file.txt
```

what happens is that all the text in `file.txt` is completely erased and there remains nothing in it.

Why does this happen? Is there something wrong with the command?

Note: There is nothing wrong with encoder. It works perfectly. I can achieve what I want with

```
cat file.txt | encoder > file2.txt
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want `sponge` ; it's in the moreutils package.

```
cat file.txt | encoder | sponge file.txt
```

Comment: but what is the problem with my command?

Comment: The problem is that opening that redirect creates the file just before you read it. i.e.   > file.txt makes a new file which replaces the file.txt you had.

Comment: Okay! So when the command it executed, the `>file.txt` part of the command causes it be opened and erased instantly. And now, because , there is nothing in the file, nothing is encoded and nothing is written to it! Hence `sponge`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Vim in Ex mode:

```sh
ex -sc '%!encoder' -cx file.txt
```

1. `%` select all lines
2. `!` run command
3. `x` save and close